# cronjob not executed for a particular file

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a cron set to run a php file but for some reason it doesn't work when the time comes. I  can manually call same file in terminal and it works fine. No error message as well.

Note: There are many more jobs set for different folder&files and they all work fine. Permissions are same as well.

Thanks

**CRON**

```
30 2 * * 1,2,3,4,5 php /var/www/html/cronjob/update-db.php
```

**PERMISSIONS**

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Nov 20 10:17 cronjob

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5808 Nov 21 17:21 update-db.php
```

- conn.php is being used by many other cronjobs and works fine.
- this code works fine when I call run it in terminal.
- every other cronjob works fine apart from this.

**CODE**

```
require_once "/var/www/html/dbfolder/conn.php";


function write_log($message)
{
    $filename = 'update-sis-assessment-column-log.txt';

    if (file_exists($filename))
    {
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
    }
    else
    {
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
        //chmod($filename, 0644);
    }

    fwrite($handle, $message . "\r\n\r\n");
    fclose($handle);

    exit;
}

if (connectDB() === true)
{
    $query = "SELECT.......";
    $rcset = mysql_query($query);

    $terms = null;

    if (@mysql_num_rows($rcset) > 0)
    {
        while ($records = mysql_fetch_array($rcset))
        {
            if (ctype_digit($records['Term']))
            {
                $terms .= "'" . substr($records['Term'], 0, 4) . "-01', ";
            }
        }

        $terms = substr($terms, 0, -2);
    }

    write_log('DONE : ' . $terms);
}
```

Comment: have you check cronlog ?

Comment: GBD where is the cronlog located?  I tried to look in /home/user/cronlog.log but that didn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that the php executable is in your path OR put the full path to php in the cron job like

```
30 2 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjob/update-db.php
```

if you are not sure where php is located you can run

```
which php
```

to get the path

Comment: I have about 20 jobs and all work fine without `/usr/bin/php` part included also file has `0755` permissions.

Comment: then i suggest you do as san4o suggested and check what the error is in a log file, one other thing you should remember is that if you are including other php files in your cron you need to make sure the paths are correct in it as well

Comment: Just discovered, same file works in different folders. Permissions on all folders and files are same. Still doesn't work in original folder though. No error.

Comment: take a good look in your update-db.php file it is probable you are including or requiring another php file with a relative path which might cause a problem like this, if you can post the contents of this file maybe it will be eaiser to find the problem

Comment: `require_once` was giving an error and I rectified it by changing it to `require_once '/var/www/html/dbfolder/conn.php'`. Now no error in `/var/spool/mail/`. `conn.php` is being used by many apps and it works 100% fine.

Comment: again it seems you are trying to write to a file with a relative path in the write_log function, make sure you know to which path the file is being written to

Answer (score 1):

Also recommend redirect output to log file and use shorter run time interval for debug

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjob/update-db.php >> /path_to_log.log

Comment: add few debug echo "some ...";  in php script. 
do you have another jobs in this crontab  ? dose they work ?